# Accessing Google cloud platform from China

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**summary**

I have started an instance on Google cloud platform (Compute Engine) half a year ago and now my employer wants to know if a Chinese collaborator can use the service I put on it from China.
How can I know without testing if the great firewall of China will block my service or if I have to switch for an other platform ?

For information I don't use Google DNS, I make a redirection from my registrar to the static IP of my server.

Comment: Which GCP products are you using?

Comment: I have an instance on Compute Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction from [Google side](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/oiPyWdmNAUs) :

> Google Cloud Platform do not have restriction on the traffic coming from China. If you are hosting website on GCE, traffic coming from the China users will not be blocked.
> That being said, Google do not have any control over the GFW blocking methods.

If you don't want to test the service with tools like [WebSitePuls](https://www.websitepulse.com/tools/china-firewall-test) or [vpnMentor](https://www.vpnmentor.com/tools/test-the-great-china-firewall/), you can start a separate service just for your customers in China:

- Spin up a VM in Hong Kong or Taiwan
- Contact a [Google Partner](https://cloud.withgoogle.com/partners/?sort-type=DISTANCE&address-location=china) in China to have services run in China mainland.

Comment: thanks, for all method you mention. I'm now 100% sure my service will work from china mainland.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be restrictions from Google side of things but  Google Cloud portal is not accessible in China as it's blocked by the great firewall so if you're even wanting to fix something in production from China you can't unless possible using a VPN.